# Como reutilizar um código HTML com JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando uma site com várias páginas e constantemente modifico o meu header, é possivel criar um único header e usa-lo em todas as páginas? (de preferencia com javascript puro)

Comment: Não me parece muito elegante, nem sei o quanto é gambiarra, mas o mais parecido que vi até hoje foi `<object type="text/html" data="outro.html"></object>` - Isto posto, quase todo software servidor de páginas (Apache, IIS, etc) tem um mecanismo proprietário para isso (sem depender de outras linguagens server side, inclusive)

Comment: Que tal usar o [pjax](https://github.com/brcontainer/pjax.js/)? :p

Answer (score 0):

A solução é a seguinte colocar os códigos que serão reutilizados em um arquivo separado e carregar com o método `load()` supondo que você tenha este arquivo que se chama main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Main page</title>
  <sript src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function(){                  
    $('#commonsection').load('reutilizavel.html');
     // Usa a função load para carregar o arquivo html
   });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="commonsection"></div>
 </body>
```

E no arquivo que será reutilizado:

```
 <script>
 (function($){ //separate scope to keep everything "private" for each module
    //do additional javascript if required
})(jQuery);
</script>
<p>...Some non-trivial content...</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Dando um Google rápido encontrei duas soluções para você, uma usando javascript puro dum exemplo da própria W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

E outra usando html puro, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001418/include-html-file-in-html-using-html5:

```html
<object name="header" type="text/html" data="./header.html"></object>
```

Comment: O problema no caso seria como estilizar a parte do template que foi incluída, né? Não creio que seja uma boa solução.

Comment: Verdade Wallace.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .myStyle {
      text-align: center;
      color: #0000ff;
    }
  </style>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Reuse of components</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="another-element"></div>
  <script>
    function render(component, element) {
      element.innerHTML = component;
    }

    function MyComponent(props) {
      return `
        <h1 class="myStyle">
          Hello, ${props.name}!
        </h1>
      `;
    }

    render(
      MyComponent({name: "David"}),
      document.getElementById("root")
    );

    render(
      MyComponent({name: "Ferreira"}),
      document.getElementById("another-element")
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este exemplo foi criado a partir de conceitos básicos do React.

This example was created from basic React concepts.